# How come this doesn't work [trying to print out a new sentence with all the constants]

Tags: java, string, indexof

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Indexof {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String newSentance = "";
    String sentance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter sentance");
    String vowels = "AEIOU";
  int len = sentance.length();
  for (int i = 0; i >=len; i++)
  {
     if(vowels.indexOf(sentance.toUpperCase().charAt(i))>0)
             {
               newSentance+=sentance.charAt(i);                                                 
     }      
}
  System.out.println(newSentance);

}

}
```

I am getting no errors in NetBeans yet it still returns nothing when printing newSentance
the .length is definitely working as it returns the number correctly if printed

what else could it be?

Comment: I dont think that your JOptionPane returns a string therefor "sentance" is equal to zero. Since len is zero your for loop doesn't run, newsentance isn't updated and nothing is printed

Comment: `length` worked perfectly, because you are printing the length of original sentence. If your `sentance` does not contain any vowels, you won't have anything in your newSentance varaible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the code with

```
int i = 0; i < len; i++
```

and

```
vowels.indexOf(sentance.toUpperCase().charAt(i)) < 0
```

results in only the constants getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

This code::

```
    for (int i = 0; i >= len; i++) {
        if (vowels.indexOf(sentance.toUpperCase().charAt(i)) > 0) {
            newSentance += sentance.charAt(i);
        }
    }
```

should be something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (vowels.indexOf(sentance.toUpperCase().charAt(i)) >= 0) {
            newSentance += sentance.charAt(i);
        }
    }
```